# Extend generic class but weaken generic binding in subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

In theory, the input paramters in a subclass method should be equivaent to or less restrictive than the input parameters of the superclass (contravariant).

What I want to do is basically create a class `A` that has a generic binding `<T extends SomeType>`, but then create a subclass `B`, with no generic binding (should allow any type) `<T>`:

```
    class A<T extends SomeType> {....}

    class B<T> extends A<T extends SomeType> { ..... }
```

Is this even possible in java or ever right from a theoretic point of view?

Comment: Does it make sense for B to extend A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that isn't correct. Consider a method declared in `A` that returns `T`:

```
abstract class A<T extends SomeType> {

    abstract T foo();
}
```

An object statically typed as `A` would be expected to conform to the bounds declared by that class:

```
A<?> a = ...;
SomeType someObject = a.foo();
```

But then if `B` does away with those bounds:

```
abstract class B<T> extends A<T> { }

class C extends B<String> {

    @Override
    String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

We have chaos:

```
A<?> a = new C();
SomeType someObject = a.foo(); // ???
```

Comment: Oh ok,  never thought of doing such misuse but I can understand why it  is made impossible to implement. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather confusing, mostly for the incorrect use of some terms, but if I understood correctly, the following example looks like what you described you wanted to do:

```
class A<T extends CharSequence> { }
class B extends A<String> { }
```

So, as per your question, the class A has a *type parameter with an upper bound of CharSequence*, whereas the class B (which extends A) has no type parameter at all.